# Can I define #regions in the visual studio 2012 t-sql editor?

Tags: sql-server, editor, visual-studio-2012

I would like to know if there is an extension that allows me to define regions inside the visual studio 2012 editor while editing user defined functions or plain t-sql queries.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to do much:

```
-- #region This is a region with t-sql code
   ...
-- #endregion
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL Visualizer](http://download.cnet.com/SQL-Visualizer/3000-10254_4-10592203.html) allows for code regions. Using that, you can start a region with `--REGION` and end it again with `-- END REGION`.

There's also the [SSMS toolpack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).

Natively, you could choose to wrap the specific blocks with BEGIN and END statements:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281835.aspx

Comment: Your first link is broken. "This domain name expired on Oct 13 2012 12:38PM "

Comment: Ouch. I copy/pasted the link from an old blogpost I wrote a while ago. I changed the link now.